# Quando devo criar Enums e Interfaces?

Tags: java

Sou iniciante na programação e gostaria que alguém me ajudasse.

Comment: Acredito que só aí você já terá material de estudo para os próximos dias. Boa sorte :D

Comment: Não há dicotomia entre elas, são para coisas diferentes por isso não são comparáveis.